# Log and compress the output of subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, subprocess

I want to redirect the output of `subprocess.call(...)` to a xz- or bzip2-compressed file.

I tried :

```
with lzma.open(log_path, "x") as log_file:
    subprocess.call(command, stdout=log_file, stderr=log_file)
```

but the resulting file isn't a valid XZ-compressed file :

```
$ xzcat logfile.xz
xzcat : logfile.xz: Format de fichier inconnu
```

(which, in French, means "unknown file format").

When I use just `cat`, the file is displayed correctly, with some weird data at the end (the command launched in the script is `rsync`) :

```
& cat logfile.xz
sending incremental file list
prog/testfile

sent 531.80K bytes  received 2.71K bytes  1.07M bytes/sec
total size is 14.21G  speedup is 26,588.26
�7zXZ�ִF�D!��}YZ
```

*logfile.xz* seems to be a semi-valid XZ archive file, filled with uncompressed data. What am I doing wrong ?

PS : It works when I do something like that :

```
output = subprocess.check_output(command)
log_file.write(output)
```

...but given that the command takes a long time (it's a backup script), I want to be able to see the log (with `xzcat`) before the end, to know what rsync is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirection happens at the file descriptor level before the child is even executed: no parent code (related to child's stdout/stderr) is run after that (Python code from `lzma` module is not run).

To compress on the fly so that you could see the output while the child process is still running, you could redirect its output to `xz` utility:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

with open('logfile.xz', 'xb', 0) as log_file:
    subprocess.call("command | xz -kezc -", shell=True,
                    stdout=log_file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Note: an ordinary `open()` is used, not `lzma.open()`: the compression is done in the `xz` subprocess.

---

If you want to compress in pure Python code then you have to pipe the data through `python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import lzma
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from shutil import copyfileobj

with lzma.open('logfile.xz', 'xb') as log_file, \
     Popen('command', stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT) as process:
    copyfileobj(process.stdout, log_file)
```

Note: `lzma.open()` is used.

Comment: Thanks ! This "no parent code" thing is weird. I chose to use pure Python.

Comment: @YdobEmos nothing weird, it is how pipelines and redirection work in the shell: `command | another >output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: I find it unintuitive, I would expect the data i send in an LZMA file to be compressed before it's written. (I was talking about your "no parent code (related to child's stdout/stderr) is run after that (Python code from lzma module is not run)" sentence).

Comment: yes, I'm talking about the same thing. Only `log_file.fileno()` result is used -- the file descriptor (an integer). It is clear that no compression occurs (no python code is run) if you know [how the redirection works (`dup2()`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279). It is not Python-specific. It might be educational, to  reimplement Popen using POSIX interface